# Python Django, url address problems

Tags: python, django

I try to use django framework and to download a file, but I have some problems about URLS.
This is my client part (HTML5):

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formfile" action='/upload' method="post">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit" id="getfile" value="Open a fits file"  />
        <span id="progressbar"></span>
    </form>
```

And to symplify, I just Write this on my views part:

```
def index(request):
    print('coucou')
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        print(file)
      return render(request, 'index.html')
```

But the "upload part" doesn't work with this urls (error 404):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('CubeVisu.views',
       url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^/upload$', 'upload_file'))
```

Comment: Did you try removing the leading `/` in `/upload` of your url patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is working when I remove the leading / in urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = patterns('CubeVisu.views',
url(r'^$', 'index'),
url(r'^upload$', 'upload_file'))
```

and in my template part as follow:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formfile" action='upload' method="post">
```

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the leading slash from your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('CubeVisu.views',
   url(r'^$', 'index'),
   url(r'^upload$', 'upload_file'))
```

also, you can use the [`url` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to refer to your urls instead of hardcoding them:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formfile" action='{% url "upload_file" %}' method="post">
```